# finding a region bouded by 4 parametric curves

Tags: curves, parametrization

suppose i have the following curves:

1. $C_1=\{(t,t+2)|t\in\mathbb{R}\}$
2. $C_2=\{(t+2,t)|t\in\mathbb{R}\}$
3. $C_3=\{(t^2+t+1,t^2-t+1)|t\in\mathbb{R}\}$
4. $C_4=\{(t^2+t+2,t^2-t+2)|t\in\mathbb{R}\}$

define $T$ as the region bounded between the 4 curves, $L:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $L(p,q)=(p+q,p-q)$ find a set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $L(S)=T$

as a hint i was told to look at $L(t,2+t^2),L(t,1+t^2)$, I found that $L(t,2+t^2)=C_4$ and $L(t,1+t^2)=C_4$

on desmos i found how the curves look and i tried finding the intersection points but that didn't get me anywhere.
any tips on i can approach these types of questions involving parametric curves?

Comment: Did you try inverting $L$?

Comment: Your question also seems to have some typos, for example $L(t,2+t^2) = (t^2+t+2,-t^2+t-2)$ and $L(t,1+t^2) = (t^2+t+1,-t^2+t-1)$.

Comment: yes my bad with that minus sign, i couldnt mange to find the inverse of the field. feels like i'm looking at the wrong direction here.

Comment: If I tell you that $L$ is a linear map with determinant $-2$, does that help you? More explicitly, you need to solve the linear system $p+q = x$, $p-q = y$.

Comment: yes ive found the determinant and p,q but i still don't really get how it can help me find the regios $S$,

Comment: $L(S) = T \implies L^{-1}(L(S)) = L^{-1}(T) \implies S = L^{-1}(T)$.

Comment: I think i got it, so $L^{-1}(p,q)=(\frac{p+q}{2},\frac{p-q}{2})$ so i insert each one of the curves $C_1,C_2,C_3,C_4$ and then i can find curves the bound the required set $S$, from there is just finding a way to define it using inequilities between p,y

Comment: Correct. Although, you can define $S$ by inequalities easily in this instance, it might be enough just to calculate the boundary of $S$, since that's how $T$ was defined as well. But if this is an assignment, it can't hurt to express it explicitly with inequalities, just in case.